# Has Qui-Gon ever visibly appeared as a Force ghost?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

We learn in *Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith* that Qui-Gon Jinn has become a Force ghost:

> Yoda: An old friend has learned the path to immortality.
>
> Obi-Wan: Who?
>
> Yoda: One who has returned from the netherworld of the Force to train me…your old Master, Qui-Gon Jinn.

Has Qui-Gon, in any media (including Legends), ever visibly appeared as a Force ghost in the same way that Obi-Wan, Yoda, and Anakin Skywalker have?

[image: Force Ghosts including a (properly aged) Anakin Skywalker, Yoda, and Obi-Wan]

Comment: +1 for using the **non-mutilated** shot of that scene.

Comment: @Angew I just read your name as "Agnew" and I thought Richard Milhouse Nixon's first VP was posting.  I was so excited.

Comment: +1 for using the real version screenShot ^^

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Yes, in *The Clone Wars*

In "[Voices](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Voices)" Qui-Gonn's spirit guided Yoda to the Force Priestesses who taught him the secret of immortality. In this case he manifested as a swarm of glowing lights:

[image]

He also manifested visibly in the episode "[Overlords](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj98ZvEhYPNAhVLIlIKHT2xBFAQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstarwars.wikia.com%2Fwiki%2FOverlords&usg=AFQjCNGJu2wfWPGmVXw0fu-JfinoGi_HHg&sig2=9PfyPmH3Q_qXwAQrIMZhHA&bvm=bv.123325700,d.aXo)." His greater power to do so here may well have been related to the strength of the Force on Mortis, the location in which he manifested.

[image]

He did this in order to warn Obi-Wan of the danger Anakin was in from the Force-wielders of Mortis:

> QUI-GON: If he is the chosen one, he will discover it here.
>
> OBI-WAN And if not?
>
> QUI-GON: Then you must realize with his power, this is a very dangerous place
>   for him to be.

Comment: It was a little unclear in "Overlords" if that was genuinely Qui-Gon, since in the same episode Anakin encountered a vision of his mother, but when he told the member of the powerful Force-user trio called "The Father" about it, The Father said it was probably a trick by another member of the trio, "The Son". So it's possible Qui-Gon was a trick as well--note that that image of Qui-Gon doesn't seem to have the transparency usually associated with Force ghosts (though the image Valorum posted from 'Voices' doesn't seem transparent either, so maybe that's not a clue).

Comment: Good point, that does make it more likely it was the real Qui-Gon.

Comment: Qui-Gon also appears in the later episode "The Ghosts of Mortis". There, he seems much less of a trick as he speaks to Anakin and dispatches the typical Jedi/Forcey "look within yourself" advice. Other than the Father's comment, there's no other evidence that it's not Qui-Gon Jinn and I find it more likely that the Father simply does not know about Force Ghosts. If it were a trick, I would expect the plot to reveal that to the viewer. Otherwise, what's the point?

Comment: @Ellesedil - The Father *definitely* knows about Force ghosts. It’s simply that the vision of Shmi was a deception, but the vision of Qui Gon wasn’t.

Answer (score 14):

In the finale episode of Obi Wan(2022), Qui-Gon Jinn appears in live action as a force ghost after nearly in every episode Obi Wan calls for his help.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

In the (non-canon) LEGO Star Wars New Yoda Chronicles, Qui-gon appears as a Force ghost in response to a call for help from Obi-wan's ghost and Yoda. It was a mistake, as Yoda and Obi-wan were communicating through the Force to someone else.

Not wanting to offend Qui-gon, Yoda lies and tells him they needed help opening a pickle jar.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

If I remember well, he was only mentioned in the movie.

He did appear in a more explicit manner in the Gameboy Advance videogame for the movie.

[image: "Obi-wan learns to preserve his identity after death through Yoda"]